# What to do about questions that have degraded because of derogatory comments

Tags: discussion

Is there anything that can be done outside of flagging specific comments?  I am looking for something like closely a question because the author has been too combative and derogatory in his comments that personally makes me want to remove the question and it's entirety  of the site as nothing good will come out of leaving up there.

referring to this question btw [What is カッコマン here?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/what-is-here)

Comment: Maybe ask a moderator to just nuke all of the comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper response is to flag a comment or post for moderator attention.  One of us will look at it and see if the comment thread is salvageable or has simply devolved into pointless bickering, at which point we will delete the entire thread.

In the case of the post you mentioned, I thought--as you said--that nothing good would come of leaving them, so I removed the thread.